# How to Create P2SH Address From Multiple Public Keys

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, public-key

this is what i tried:

1. i created a reedem script : [OP_2, PB1 Length(1-byte), PB1, PB2 Length(1-byte), PB2, PB3 Length(1-byte), PB3, 83 (OP_3), 174 (OP_CHECKMULTISIG)]
2. Hash = calcualte ripemd160 of sha256 of reedem script
3. script_pubkey = [OP_160, Hash, OP_EQUAL]

after step 3 i don't know what to do to get the address. i know that the step 5 will be the base58 of step 4 and i don't know what is it. i saw some sources from python libraries but i could not figure out what they do.

so what is the step 4?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 4 involves prefixing the RIPEMD160(SHA256) hash of the redeem script with a network-specific version byte (note it differs for mainnet and testnet). For a P2SH address on the Bitcoin mainnet, you prefix the hash with the byte `0x05`. This step is crucial as it denotes the address type and network. The complete data structure before Base58Check encoding will be: `[version byte] + [Hash]`.

After prefixing, next step includes Base58Check encoding, which includes calculating a checksum by taking the first four bytes of the `SHA256(SHA256([version byte] + [Hash]))` and appending them to the end of `[version byte] + [Hash]`. The entire structure is then encoded in Base58 to produce the final address.